# How can i compare two lists of words, change the words that are in common, and print the result in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

if i have a list of strings-

```
common = ['the','in','a','for','is']
```

and i have a sentence broken up into a list-

```
lst = ['the', 'man', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'barrel']
```

how can i compare the two,and if there are any words in common, then print the full string again as a title. I have part of it working but my end result prints out the newly changed in common strings as well as the original.

```
new_title = lst.pop(0).title()
for word in lst:
    for word2 in common:
        if word == word2:
            new_title = new_title + ' ' + word

    new_title = new_title + ' ' + word.title()

print(new_title)
```

output:

```
The Man is Is in In the The Barrel
```

so I'm trying to get it so that the lower case words in common, stay in the new sentence, without the originals, and without them changing into title case.

Comment: I think you need to clarify this - what is the expected output if `common =` ... 0) as it is now, 1) `[]`, 2) `['is']`, and 3) `= lst`

Comment: sorry for not being clear. basically trying to create a title, where common words are kept in lower case. The common words were on a separate list, and the title is any string passed into my function. although i had worked it through to separating the common words, and reprinting it with the string titled, I was stuck at how i could reform my sentence, without doubling up on the found common words. (ps i also forgot to put 'is' in original common list, oops) thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> new_title = ' '.join(w.title() if w not in common else w for w in lst)
>>> new_title = new_title[0].capitalize() + new_title[1:]
'The Man Is in the Barrel'
```

Comment: thank you. this worked, and really helped with my assignment.

Comment: @GP89 No, calling `capitalize()` on the entire string will lowercase every letter other than the first.

Answer (score 0):

If all you’re trying to do is to see whether any of the elements of `lst` appear in `common`, you can do

```
>>> common = ['the','in','a','for']
>>> lst = ['the', 'man', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'barrel']
>>> list(set(common).intersection(lst))
['the', 'in']
```

and just check to see whether the resulting list has any elements in it.

If you want the words in `common` to be lowercased and you want all of the other words to be uppercased, do something like this:

```
def title_case(words):
    common = {'the','in','a','for'}
    partial = ' '.join(word.title() if word not in common else word for word in words)
    return partial[0].capitalize() + partial[1:]

words = ['the', 'man', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'barrel']
title_case(words) # gives "The Man Is in the Barrel"
```

Comment: Thanks for both explanations.

Comment: @Malvek No problem. On a side note, if your question on Stack Overflow is related to a homework assignment, it's best to state that up front, so that people will help you understand the problem instead of just doing the work for you :-)